# Updating user's API call based on user premium status using Djagno custom throttle

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a custom throttle that checks a user's account premium status when making an API call. Looking at the docs I believe I wrote the custom throttle correctly updated my settings.

I'm building a translation website where a user clicks a button on a piece of text and provides translation returned from a translator API.

Django Settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'premium': '5/day',
        'user': "1/day",
    }
}
```

throttles.py

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class UserType(UserRateThrottle):
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        user_type = getattr(request.user, 'premium_account', None)   
        if user_type == False:
            request.scope = 'user'
        else:
            request.scope = 'premium'
        return super().allow_request(request,view)
```

How I'm passing my UserType into my API.

```
class Translator(APIView):

    throttle_classes = [UserType]
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

I tried writing a custom `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASES` item and it was counting any interaction with my website (like logging in) against the throttle rate.